# salesforce apex refresh VF pageblock section

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying to refresh a page block section based on the value of a select list. Here is the VF:

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!reasonCode}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!reasonCodes}"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="oncomplete" action="{!isAcceptedReasonCode}" reRender="orders"/>
                    </apex:selectList>                
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="orders" rendered="{!isAcceptedRC==true}" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Order Number" for="odNum"/>
                <apex:inputText id="odNum" value="{!OrderNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I have tried a bunch of different events, but none seem to work. Here is the isAcceptedReasonCode function:

```
public PageReference isAcceptedReasonCode (){
        if(reasonCode == 'Accepted Offer') {
            isAcceptedRC = true;       
        }else {
            isAcceptedRC = false;
        }   
        return null;
    }
```

This seems pretty straightforward but it doesn't seem to work... of course i change the select list to be = 'Accepted Offer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add apex:outputPanel above apex:pageBlockSection and reRender outputpanel when Selection options is changed.

Sample Code:

```
       <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!reasonCode}">
                     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Test" itemValue="Test"></apex:selectOption>
                     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Accepted Offer" itemValue="Accepted Offer"></apex:selectOption>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!isAcceptedReasonCode}" reRender="testPanel"/>

                </apex:selectList>  
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem >                  
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:outputPanel id="testPanel">
         <apex:pageBlockSection id="orders" rendered="{!isAcceptedRC}" >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Order Number" for="odNum"/>
            <apex:inputText id="odNum" value="{!OrderNumber}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>  
      </apex:pageBlock >
```